# Openbox fails on login

Tags: linux, xorg, window-manager, openbox, desktop-environments

X throws this error:

```
Xsession: unable to launch "/usr/share/xsessions/openbox.xsession" Xsession
--- "/usr/share/xsessions/openbox.xsession"  not found; Falling back to 
default session.
```

But a trip to the Command line reveals:

```
sam@Aristotle:/usr/share/xsessions$ ls 
...
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  164 2011-05-22 12:27 openbox.xsession
...
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, openbox 3.5.0, and X.Org X Server 1.10.4

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it reports `not found` for you, but you should [make the file executable](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/XWindow-User-HOWTO/runningx.html)* as root:

> *[The] files in a user's home directory may be created or modified by the user any time and must be **executable** shell scripts.*

To do this you want to enable the execute permission on your file, as root:

```
$ sudo chmod a+x /usr/share/xsessions/openbox.xsession
```

Optionally you can also use a file in your hone directory:

```
$ cp /usr/share/xsessions/openbox.xsession ~/.xsession (not ~/.Xsession)
$ chmod a+x ~/.xsession
```